# update varbinary field from another table

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to update TABLE_A varbinary column from TABLE_B varbinary field. There are 280,000 documents in both tables. I have inserted all these documents from the file system recursively using c# code to TABLE_B varbinary column. It took approx 3 hours to complete. Now I am trying update TABLE_A rows from TABLE_B using this query. It started this 11 hours ago and still running. I applied indexes on both columns. I appreciate any suggestions.

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.doc = T2.doc
FROM TABLE_A T1
INNER JOIN TABLE_B T2
    ON rtrim(ltrim(T1.path)) = rtrim(ltrim(T2.path))
```

Comment: Is the `doc` field the contents of the actual document? How large is the table? At least I would recommend doing the rtrim + ltrim on the table before this, and removing it from the update, since it could easily cause indexes not to be used

Comment: yes. approx 250gb. will try to remove rtrim, ltrim and run it again. thanks

Comment: understand that indexes slow down inserts and updates but speeds up reads so there is a catch here. I [would do this in batches](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes) though. Something like: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86520/95107

Answer (score 0):

```
select 1;
while(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
begin
   UPDATE TOP(5) T1
   SET T1.doc = T2.doc
   FROM TABLE_A T1
   INNER JOIN TABLE_B T2
   ON rtrim(ltrim(T1.path)) = rtrim(ltrim(T2.path))
end
```

You can do the update in batches as given above. Updating all the rows at once will take a long time